# container of template class in c++

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a template, which may be used with different stl map (`map<int, int>`, `map<int, char>`, etc.), as follows.

```
template <typename Map> struct TriMaps
{
  Map& next;
  Map& prev;
  Map& curr;
};
```

so, `TriMaps<init, int> intTriMaps;` `TriMaps<int, char> charTriMaps;`

Then, is it possible to have a container of the above TriMaps, in different type? e.g.

```
vector <TriMaps> vecMaps;
```

which contain intTriMaps and charTriMaps? Usually container requires the same type. But I really need a container for my case. No boost or third library available.

Comment: Yes. You need to specify the argument types for `TriMaps`, like `vector<TriMaps<int, int>> vecMaps;`

Comment: yes, but a specific instantiation (for example, `TriMaps<map<int, int>>`)

Comment: @jrok, `TriMaps` is expecting only one type argument. You gave example taking two.

Comment: @Ajay Oh, right. So, `vector<TriMaps<map<int, int>>>`

Answer (score 1):

First determine and finalize what this class template `TriMaps` is expected to do. In C++, you must initialize a reference to something. You probably need a non-reference type (or a pointer type).  Consider:

```
template <typename Map> 
struct TriMaps
{
  Map next;
  Map prev;
  Map curr;
};
```

Usage:

```
TriMaps<int> IntMaps;
vector<TriMaps<int>> iv;
```

If you need two template type argument, you can do this way:

```
template <typename MapType1, typename MapType2>
struct TriMaps
{
   MapType1 a;
   Maptype2 b;
};
```

Usage:

```
TriMaps<int, float> IntMaps;
vector<TriMaps<int, float>> iv;
```

**EDIT:**

Carefully understand that following simple class **will not** compile.

```
class TriMap
{
   int & ref_int;
};
```

One approach is to refer a global variable (just to make it compile), or take an `int&` via a constructor.

```
// Approach 1
int global;
class TriMap
{
  int & ref_int;
public:
   TriMap() : ref_int(global) {}
};

// Approach 2
class TriMap
{
   int & ref_int;
public:
   TriMap(int & outer) : ref_int(outer) {}
};
```

Comment: i am sorry Ajay, probably i did not describe my problem clearly enough. what I want is a container, which can contains different types (map <int, int> or map <int, char>). This is not possible, as element of container requires to be the same type, unless I define some base class.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `std::vector` of different type

but if you can have base class

```
struct TriMapBase { virtual ~TriMapBase() = default; };
template <typename Map> struct TriMaps : TriMapBase { /* Your implementation */ };
```

Then you may have:

```
TriMapBase<std::map<int, int>> mapint;
TriMapBase<std::map<int, char>> mapchar;
std::vector<TriMapBase*> v = {&mapint, &mapchar};
```

but you have to use virtual functions
or `dynamic_cast` to retrieve the correct type afterward...
or use